# Code-review entire project, not just shelveset, using TFS code-review

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfs-code-review

TFS 2012 includes excellent support for code-reviewing changesets. However, we have some legacy projects that we want to code review. Once the quality has been brought up to spec, we will start using changeset reviews - however the code changes infrequently, so it's not practical to just review the changesets and improve quality through natural code-churn.

Is it possible to code-review a file or project in it's entirety, rather than just a changeset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TFS 2012 this is not an option. If the project is small enough there is a trick, you can right-click the folder in source control, do "checkout..." and then request the review. That allows you to review up to 4000 files at a time.

In TFS 2013 a new feature was added, [Lightweight Code Commenting in Web Access](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/collaborative-commenting.aspx). This allows you to annotate the code directly from the code tab in Web Access.

There are 3rd party code review options available on Codeplex, I haven't used them in quite a while, but they might add something more to your liking:

- [Team review](https://teamreview.codeplex.com/)
- [Team Code Review Workflow](https://tfscodereviewflow.codeplex.com/)
- [Malevich](https://malevich.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That checkout tip is brilliant - perfect for what I want (none of the projects are 4000 files - we wouldn't be manually code-reviewing them if they were!). Thanks very much :)